# android xamarin timer not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, timer, xamarin.android

i am making an android app in xamarin using c#, and using the following code to repeat task, but unfortunately the code is not working properly,

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Timer timer= new Timer();
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Interval = 2000;
                timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
                timer.Start();
                }

            private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "asasasas", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have UI invocation in your `async` timer callback method `Timer_Elapsed`
All UI invocation need to pass through the MainThread, or it will result to thread exception

Wrap Toast with RunOnUiThread like the example below

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   RunOnUiThread(()=>Toast.MakeText(this, "asasasas", ToastLength.Long).Show();)
}
```

Comment: thanks alot @iamlcarus, one more question, if i want to put any logic i-e want to insert record in db after five seconds, do i still have to use RunOnUiThread??

Comment: @CodeBank just the UI invocations need to be executed withing RunOnUiThread. All other code can be freely placed outside (or inside) the RunOnUiThread block